# Are there adapters for MiniDisplay port screens to HDMI video cards

Tags: displayport, compatibility

I am wondering if I can connect an Apple Cinema Display with a MiniDisplay port to an HDMI video card.

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer is yes.**

It's not a common conversion (normally it's a DisplayPort to HDMI), but it can be done.  To do so, you need an [active adapter](http://radnex.us/hdmi-to-displayport-active-adapter) to go from HDMI to DispayPort because the signaling is completely different and needs to be recreated so it will work.

Comment: Looks like this could work with one of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-DisplayPort-Video-Cable-Adapter-Black/dp/B003N3DTKY/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1528381407&sr=1-1&keywords=displayport+to+minidisplayport).

Comment: I'm not sure; you'll have to test.  Generally, the conversion goes in the order described (source to output) and your link is "DisplayPort *to* HDMI".  Conversion isn't (usually) bidirectional.  You want to go HDMI (source) to DisplayPort (output)